# Change table elements when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that dynamically creates a table. How can I change the column colors when the checkbox is clicked. My function looks like this:

```
function addRow() {

    var myName = document.getElementById("name");
    var age = document.getElementById("age");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value= Date();

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = date;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= age.value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= '<input type="checkbox" value = "check">';
```

Comment: Where is your problem? How to know when the checkbox was clicked or how to change the color?

Comment: Both to be honest, would appreciate any input

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your project?  Judging by your responses to the answers below (and your quoted code) you have not.  You either want to add it to your project (`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` for version 2.1.1) or if you don't want to use jQuery you should remove the tag from your question.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way could be to change

```
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= '<input type="checkbox" value = "check">';
```

to

```
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= '<input type="checkbox" value = "check" onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor=\'#f00\';">';
```

just added an `onclick` attribute so that when user clicks on this checkbox it will change the `background-color` to red `#f00`

if you want to toggle the colors

```
function toggleColor (  thisObj )
{
    var classes = thisObj.parentNode.classname;
    if ( classes.split(" ").indexOf( "blue-color" ) == -1 )
    {
       thisObj.parentNode.classname += " blue-color";
    }
    else
    {
      thisObj.parentNode.classname = classes.split( " blue-color" ).join( "" );
    }
}
```

invoke it as

```
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= '<input type="checkbox" value = "check" onclick="toggleColor(this)">';
```

and also

```
.blue-color {
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

Comment: This works! However, when I unclick it, I want the color to change again. Sort of a toggle function. Any ideas?

Comment: @krukan459 sorry but this is not part of your original question, please raise a new one for this.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged jquery

CSS

```
.blue-color {
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

JS

```
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    $(this).closest("td").toggleClass("blue-color");
});
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/DStwkwvLIvGjr1bFjWIb?p=preview

Comment: Nothing happens when I try this solution, do I need to include something more?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that jquery is loaded:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Register click event for the checkbox and update the containing `<td>` background color through CSS if the checkbox is clicked :

```
 $("#myTableData").on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){

        $(this).closest('td').css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
          $(this).closest('td').css("backgroundColor", "#aaa");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Nothing at all happens when I try this solution, do I need to include something else?

Comment: You need to load jquery library

Answer (score 0):

Just add an onclick event to your checkbox and call a function to change the back ground color for all columns you want. Something like below

```
<input type="checkbox" value = "check" onclick="ChangeBackgroundColor(this)">
```

then use a simple function like below to change background color

```
function ChangeBackgroundColor(status){
          if(status.checked =='true'){
            document.getElementById('name').style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
           document.getElementById('age').style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
           document.getElementById('date').style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
   } 
       else{
            //do nothing if not checked or change it to previous colors, whatever you want
          }

}
```

Hope it helps.